# WPF many same events are regitering when rendering view

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question, I have a view and in that view I am having combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectsBrowserAxmModules}" SelectedValuePath="AxmModuleId" DisplayMemberPath="AxmModuleName"  
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedAxmModule, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{Binding BrowserComboBoxWatermark}" Height="2" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    SelectionChanged="ComboBox_CurrentBrowserAxmChanged" >
```

And so event looks like:

```
private void ComboBox_CurrentBrowserAxmChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
((CurrentsHistoryViewModel)DataContext).GetCurrentsModuleCommand.Execute(sender);
}
```

And every time i change view to different one and back to this view it looks like this event is registering anew so for example if i go to different view go back and go different view and back again this event will fire 4 times.

I tried

```
Loaded -= ComboBox_CurrentBrowserAxmChanged;
```

But no luck is there any way to unregistered those redundant events.

Comment: what if you put `e.Handled = true` in the event handler?

Comment: No luck, as i set true on processed event not on every event from that combobox

Comment: Except the XAML declaration, you're not manually attaching the event handler anywhere?

Comment: How do you "change view to different one"?

Comment: Do you change the ProjectsBrowserAxmModules value during Unloaded and Loaded Event?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, combobox SelectedValue property gets changed somehow and internally it calls your combobox selection changed event. have debugger point in setter of SelectedAxmModule property. hope you will find given property is hitting when you are switching screens.

My suggestion is , to remove selectionChanged event. and use event/delegate for same purpose.

Code Snipt:

```
public class AxmModule: NotifierModel
    {
    public static event MyEventHandler ValueChanges;
            public delegate void MyEventHandler(string Value);
         private string _selectedAxmModule ;
            public string SelectedAxmModule 
            {
                get
                {
                    return _selectedAxmModule ;
                }
                set
                {
                    _selectedAxmModule = value;
                    if (ValueChanged!= null)
                    {
                        ValueChanged(_selectedAxmModule );
                        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedAxmModule ");
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Register it in your view Code behind/ viewmodel

```
   AxmModule.ValueChanged+= AxmModule_ValueChanged;

  public void AxmModule_ValueChanged(string value)
        {
     // your code
        }
```

Hope, this will resolve your issue.